# How to make previous commits with EOL issues consistent in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, eol

We have a Mercurial repository with a standard of using Unix-style line endings.

If a user hasn't noticed EOL issues when committing a file - they may be 'helpfully' hidden by the diff tool - then it's a pain to fix down the line unless it's noticed immediately.

Is there a way to use "hg convert" (or similar) to re-create the repository with consistent line endings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do it, but you could use `hg transplant` with the `--filter` option to reapply those changesets in a corrected form and then `hg strip` the wrong ones.  It'll be enough of a hassle that you'll probably put a `pretxnchangegroup` hook on your *centralish* repo to prevent folks from pushing them in the future.

Comment: Bother. Our centralish repository doesn't support `pretxnchangegroup` but that would have been my normal preventative solution. I like the idea of using `transplant` - I could pull all changesets into a parallel branch (via a line endings filter) then strip. Thanks.